# Why is the bending mode of carbon dioxide harmonic?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, orbitals, anharmonic-oscillators

Here's a simple classical model of a carbon dioxide molecule:

[image: carbon dioxide bending mode]

This gif illustrates the "bending mode" vibration.

If the carbon atom moves a small distance $\mathrm{d}x,$ then the springs' change of length $\mathrm{d}L$ should be second order in $\mathrm{d}x,$
$$ \mathrm{d}L \propto (\mathrm{d}x)^2$$

Assuming the springs are at their rest length when $\mathrm{d}x = 0,$ the potential energy change is
$$\mathrm{d}U \propto (\mathrm{d}L)^2 \propto (\mathrm{d}x)^4$$

This isn't harmonic, but in reality the bending mode is basically harmonic.

Of course this classical model is wrong; one needs to find molecular orbitals to do the honest calculation. I suppose the answer is "if you were to somehow solve Schrodinger's equation for all the particles involved here, you'd see that the energy is second order, not fourth", but I'm hoping the reason for this can be broken down in some more intelligible, if hand-wavy, way. E.g. something about orbitals repelling each other.

Comment: 1/2 As I understand it, your calculation is $\mathrm{d}U\propto(\sqrt{L^2+\mathrm{d}x^2}-L_0)^2-(L-L_0)^2$, where $L_0$ ($L$) is the equilibrium (initial) length of one double bond. This is $(1-L_0L^{-1})\mathrm{d}x^2+\frac14L_0L^{-3}\mathrm{d}x^4+O(\mathrm{d}x^6)$, so your concern arises if $L=L_0$, i.e. if the initial positions of each oxygen atom relative to carbon are determined by separately minimizing the energy in each double bond. By contrast, the harmonic model requires a positive $\mathrm{d}x^2$ coefficient.

Comment: 2/2 I was hoping to argue $L>L_0$ from small charges due to electronegativity differences, but the double bond's length is only 116 pm in carbon dioxide, as opposed to the somewhat longer 123 pm in carbonyls. My guess is the oscillation reduces the horizontal spacing between atoms rather than just increasing the bond length, so can der Waal forces also need to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

It's bending. The O atoms will move through an arc such that their distance to the C atom is very nearly constant. There will be some minute change of length of the springs, but not much.

This is especially true for small bending angles. As a first-order approx, you can ignore the the change in length of the springs.

Comment: If it's just "bending", i.e., the springs aren't really changing length, then what provides the restoring force? I suppose it's likely some feature of the interaction between the C and O's that's not captured by the spring model as shown, but it would be helpful to expand your answer to address this!

Comment: Take a metal spring and bend it sideways then let it go. Sproing! What's to expand? The at-rest molecule is straight because that's the lowest energy configuration. You are bending it sideways away from the minimum. It wants to go back.

Comment: @BobaFit Sure, in the case of a metal spring the response will, for small angles, be approximately Hooke's law: the restoring force in linear proportion to the distortion. And sure: it is plausible that in the case of the carbon dioxide molecule the force response is approximately linear too. However, we have only one data point: that the straight configuration is of lowest energy. That single data point does not exclude the possibility that the energy increases sharply with increasing bending. In that sense we have no means to exclude the possibility that the potential is cubic, or quartic.

Comment: @Cleonis It's given in the question that it is SHO, but wonders how it can be due to the dx^2. It is not asking why you can treat small displacements as similar to Hooke's law.

Comment: The restoring force is chemical: you can think of the electronic orbital energy as increasing when you distort the molecule away from its optimal geometry. The potential energy surface will vary no matter how you move the nuclei, but the primitive motion we call bending is essentially just a change in the bonding angle. About the equilibrium geometry, the lowest term of consequence is the parabolic term. Higher order terms are present, but the actual PES is surprisingly harmonic even for extremely light nuclei.

Answer (score 0):

The leading order effect is the out-of-plane bending, not due to the change of length of the spring.

You can interpret it thinking at the Carbon atom as the hinge of 2 swings that connect the Carbon atom with the two atoms of Oxygen, that repel each others.

I'll attach the eigen-analysis of the mechanical model described above, considering only the vertical motion of the atoms as the degrees of freedom. You can easily see that this model is linear in the position of the the C atom, $x$, and the angle $\theta$, and thus in the lateral displacement $L = \ell \theta$ of the atoms of oxygen w.r.t. to the equilibrium configuration.

[image]